# An application of mean value theorem in Banach spaces

Tags: calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations

I am reading [this](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPC_1996__13_5_567_0.pdf) paper and I did not understand a statement done in the final of the page $581$:

> $$I_{Q_{\lambda}}(z_{\delta}) - I_{Q_{\lambda}}(u_n) \geq - \frac{1}{n} ||z_{\delta} - u_n||$$
> and by mean value theorem, we then have
> $$\langle I_{Q_{\lambda}}'(u_n), z_{\delta} - u_n \rangle + o(||z_{\delta} - u_n||) \geq - \frac{1}{n} ||z_{\delta} - u_n||.$$

The mean value theorem gives

$$||I_{Q_{\lambda}}(z_{\delta}) - I_{Q_{\lambda}}(u_n)|| \leq ||I_{Q_{\lambda}}'(u_n)|| \ ||z_{\delta} - u_n|| + o(||z_{\delta} - u_n||).$$

How this last inequality give the penultimate inequality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expression after "we then have" is bounded below by minus the product of the norms. Does it help ?

Comment: I think this not help me, but thanks for the attempt! I think that I can get the inequality using the Taylor's formula instead of the mean value theorem, I am trying this right now.

Answer (score 1):

I used Taylor's formula instead of the mean value theorem to obtain the inequality.

From Taylor's formula,

$$I_{Q_{\lambda}}(z_{\delta}) - I_{Q_{\lambda}}(u_n) = \langle I_{Q_{\lambda}}'(u_n), z_{\delta} - u_n \rangle + o(||z_{\delta} - u_n||).$$

Thus,

$$\langle I_{Q_{\lambda}}'(u_n), z_{\delta} - u_n \rangle + o(||z_{\delta} - u_n||) = I_{Q_{\lambda}}(z_{\delta}) - I_{Q_{\lambda}}(u_n) \geq - \frac{1}{n} ||z_{\delta} - u_n||.$$